# vba excel - Pivot Tablle Calculated Field

Tags: vba, excel

I have developed a Pivot Table and need to add a calculated field. Rather than using the 'named' (row) fields, I would like to use the 'reference' field in my calculation. The formula works fine using the 'named' field. but not when using a 'reference'. Below is part of the code and where is goes wrong. Appreciate your guidance and help.

```
'/-------------
'/ Insert Data Field
'/-------------
With pTable
With .PivotFields(wksDSheet.Cells(1, 5).Value)
    .Orientation = xlDataField
    .Position = 1
    .Function = xlSum
    'NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
    .Caption = "Actual Spent"
End With
s1 = pTable.PivotFields(wksDSheet.Cells(1, 5).Value)

With .PivotFields(wksDSheet.Cells(1, 6).Value)
    .Orientation = xlDataField
    .Position = 2
    .Function = xlSum
    '.NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
    .Caption = "YmBudget To date"
End With

With .PivotFields(wksDSheet.Cells(1, 7).Value)
    .Orientation = xlDataField
    .Position = 3
    .Function = xlSum
    '.NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
    .Caption = "YrBudget To Year"
s2 = pTable.PivotFields(wksDSheet.Cells(1, 7).Value)
End With
```

End With

```
'/-------------------
'/ Insert Calculated Fields
'/-------------------
'/ The Name and Formula

''' This works''''>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
' pTable.CalculatedFields.Add Name:="Available", _
    Formula:="=YrBudget - Actual"

''' This does NOT work ''''>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
pTable.CalculatedFields.Add Name:="Available", _
    Formula:="=s2 - s1"


With pTable.PivotFields("Available")
    .Orientation = xlDataField
     .Function = xlSum
    .Position = 4
   '.NumberFormat = "0.00"
    .Caption = "Net Available"
End With
```

Comment: What are `s2` and `s1`?

Comment: Spotted them in the code. I think you need: `"=" & s2 & " - " & s1` to build the formula.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works perfectly.